# Django 1.7 upgrade error: AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-1.7

I am trying to upgrade a project from Django 1.6 to 1.7. So far, I have created a new virtualenv with all the same installs and upgraded the Django version to the new release. I need to upgrade from South, but had errors doing so, so I thought I'll initially just try runserver, and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
        app_config.import_models(all_models)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/Users/Name/Dev/tps/products/models.py", line 127, in <module>
        watson.register(Product.objects.exclude(productimage=None))
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 698, in exclude
        return self._filter_or_exclude(True, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 707, in _filter_or_exclude
        clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in add_q
        clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1314, in _add_q
        current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1138, in build_filter
        lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1076, in solve_lookup_type
        _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1339, in names_to_path
        field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 416, in get_field_by_name
        cache = self.init_name_map()
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 445, in init_name_map
        for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 563, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
        cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 577, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
        for klass in self.apps.get_models():
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
        result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 168, in get_models
        self.check_models_ready()
      File "/Users/Name/.virtualenvs/test17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
        raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Any ideas what might be causing the error and how to fix it?

Comment: did you removed south from installed apps ?

Comment: yes, I followed the steps here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/) and I still get the error

Comment: note: I am using django-allauth, and doing the same to the migrations in that app, not sure if that is causing issues.

Comment: I repeatedly got this error when doing runserver or anything with manage.py. This was long after a sucessful upgrade to 1.7. It turned out to be nothing to do with that, but a bunch of code I had copied for reference and left at the bottom of a models.py file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is with this line ("/Users/Name/Dev/tps/products/models.py", line 127):

```
watson.register(Product.objects.exclude(productimage=None))
```

You try to reference a model at the import time. It is no longer possible in Django 1.7. Django 1.7 allows you to use your models only after all of the applications are loaded. You should move this call to the `ready` callback of `AppConfig`, like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'products'

    def ready(self):
        Product = self.get_model('Product')
        watson.register(Product.objects.exclude(productimage=None))
```

Then you should reference this `AppConfig` in the `__init__.py` of your `products` app:

```
default_app_config = 'products.apps.ProductsConfig'
```

Where `apps` is the name of the module where you put the config.

Relevant Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/

Overall, because of this change, migrating to Django 1.7 is not as easy as one would like it to be. Here are some troubleshooting tips: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks Vasily, I'll have a go at making these changes and let you know how they go. This is the third party search app Watson, so I guess they'll be needing to make these changes to their app for 1.7

Comment: Brilliant, that did it! I had multiple searches registered with Watson, and I put them all in there. I just had to add "import Watson" to apps.py

Comment: I was getting this error because my wsgi.py file was out of date, django 1.7 has a new format for this and after fixing this everything was fine using gunicorn 19.1.0 (19.1.1 is broken).  Everything was fine with runserver though so I only hit the issue in prod deployment.

Comment: I repeatedly got this error when doing runserver or anything with manage.py. This was long after a sucessful upgrade to 1.7. It turned out to be nothing to do with that, but a bunch of code I had copied for reference and left at the bottom of a models.py file. In django 1.7 if you get this error, the error will probably be in models.py somewhere

Answer (score 16):

I was getting this error when I updated my django project template to 1.7. One thing that changed is the wsgi.py file so that needed some updating. Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 93, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/middleware/locale.py", line 23, in __init__
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 372, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/site/kpm/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    admin.autodiscover()
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 23, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 67, in autodiscover_modules
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/kpmteam/staging/deploys/20141029-115625/site/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

This is what the wsgi.py file looked like:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And now (running Django 1.7 with gunicorn 19.1.0):

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Changing the last two lines fixed it. Note your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE might be different, typically it is "project_name.settings"

Answer (score 14):

I'm late to the party, but if you're using django-registration, you'll have to switch to django-regitration-redux.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration-redux/

See this answer: [Django-registration compatibility issue with django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037807/django-registration-compatibility-issue-with-django-1-7)

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution doing:

```
import django
```

`django.setup()`