# Django 1.7 foreign key queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I encountered a problem with Django 1.7. When I want make my migration I raise this exception : 
Models aren't loaded yet. 
I tried solution said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load) but it doesn't work.
I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680803/django-1-7-upgrade-error-appregistrynotready-models-arent-loaded-yet) but I can't how do it with my models.
Error is due to person_type field on UserProfile Class. When I removed it migrations works.

```
class Typo_model(BaseModel):
    key   = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class UserProfile(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
    person_type = models.ForeignKey(Typo_model, queryset =
    Typo_model.objects.filter(cle="person_type"), verbose_name="Person type")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can set `queryset` on a `ForeignKey`. Purhaps `limit_choices_to` is what you are looking for. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Like this:

```
person_type = models.ForeignKey(
    Typo_model,
    limit_choices_to={'cle': 'person_type'}
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was an ugly mistake !