# Error with starting Django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I tried running python3 manage.py runserver on a django repo I pulled and am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 177, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 72, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Vers`enter code here`ions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: You most likely have a missing dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680803/django-1-7-upgrade-error-appregistrynotready-models-arent-loaded-yet