# How to solve AppRegistryNotReady at Django(1.7.1)

Tags: django, django-templates

After I installed django-registration, thing happened.
I put app named "registration" under the installed-apps. And it is now giving me. I tried to solve this issue but dont't have any idea how to tackle it. In the Stackoverflow, I found similar problems and solutions for this. But I cannot add command like "import django" and "django.setup()" to registry.py file. I've done also work like changing wsgi.py file

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 136, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

This is my wsgi.py file.

```
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "realpro.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I appreciate any feedback for this problem for me and everyone who starts to install "django-registration" program.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the fork that is actually maintained as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037807/django-registration-compatibility-issue-with-django-1-7)? Since you said you installed 'django-registration' and not 'django-registration-redux', that is probably your best bet if you don't want to fix the project yourself.

Comment: Thanks I reinstalled django-registtration-redux and it is now helping me do what I've wanted to. Thanks!